# Android M calendar write event issue

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-calendar

I have developed an Android App which writes events to the device calendar. It is working well in Android versions below 6. But is not working in Android Marshmallow. There are no installation issues, no errors either in Android M. I have properly used targetSdkVersion as 23.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you [request the permission at runtime](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have set permissions to read & write calendar in the manifest file. As mentioned the App works for Android versions below 6

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question. Do you request the permission at runtime?

Comment: @ianhanniballake  I am not requesting permissions at runtime. So, does that mean that Android 6 does not allow Calendar events to be written even though I have set permissions to read & write calendar in the manifest file. Thanks for your response.

Comment: That's what the link I included says.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you so much

Comment: @ianhanniballake If I downgrade the targetSdkVersion to 22 will Android 6 allow Calendar writes without having to request the permission at runtime.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I could make the App Android M compatible by requesting the permission at run time. Thanks again

Comment: @ianhanniballake However, one of my user has reported that my app could not write to the Calendar. It should have worked even without the permission request at run time since that user is having a Nexus phone running Android 4.3